# List<object> select use multiple values

Tags: c#, linq, listitem

I want to find a specific value from a List with the method select.

My code :

```
public class Calc
{
    public int IdCalc { get; set; }
    public double Result { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Calc myC1 = new Calc();
        List<Calc> liCalc = new List<Calc>();
        myC1.IdCalc = -1;
        myC1.Result = 20.2;
        myC1.Number = 1;

        Calc myC2 = new Calc();
        myC2.IdCalc = 22;
        myC2.Result = 20.2;
        myC2.Number = 2;
        liCalc.Add(myC1);
        liCalc.Add(myC2);

        double getResult = ((Calc)(liCalc.Select(Calc => Calc.IdCalc = 22 && Calc.Number = 2))).Result;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

As you can see my List contains two objects: `myC1` and `myC2`.

I just want to find the value of Result when IdCalc = 22 and Number = 2 thats why I tried to use Select but it's not working with two parameters.

Comment: use where instead of select and its == single = is for assignment

Comment: Once you use the where the cast can be taken out

Comment: Hi I tried Where but I have the same problem, I have the error impossible to cast 'WhereListIterator` in type Calc. I try this : double getResult = ((Calc)(liCalc.Where(Calc => Calc.IdCalc == 22 && Calc.Number == 2))).Result;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Where`, which lets you filter results based on some criteria, however that will return an `IEnumerable<Calc>`. Since you are only looking for a single result, you should use `First` which also takes a predicate and only returns the first `Calc`:

```
Calc myCalc = liCalc.First(c => c.IdCalc == 22 && c.Number == 2);
double result = myCalc.Result;
```

This will throw an exception if there is nothing that matches the filter, though. If you're worried about that, use `FirstOrDefault` which will return `null` if there is no match.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Calc
{
    public int IdCalc { get; set; }
    public double Result { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Calc myC1 = new Calc();
        List<Calc> liCalc = new List<Calc>();
        myC1.IdCalc = -1;
        myC1.Result = 20.2;
        myC1.Number = 1;

        Calc myC2 = new Calc();
        myC2.IdCalc = 22;
        myC2.Result = 20.2;
        myC2.Number = 2;
        liCalc.Add(myC1);
        liCalc.Add(myC2);
        double getResult = liCalc.First(item => item.IdCalc == 22 && item.Number == 2).Result; //Note that this will throw an exception if no item in the list satisfies the condition.

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following statement

```
double getResult = liCalc.Where(Calc => Calc.IdCalc = 22 && Calc.Number = 2))).Select(y=>y.Result).FirstOrDefault();
```

Essentially using Where() followed by Select().